# setting up a belongs_to relation when the foreign key is stored in metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails 4 application, I have an STI model that stores metadata in a jsonb column.

Base Class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Subclass:

```
class JobPost < Post
  # has a jsonb column for metadata
end
```

One of the data attributes in the metadata column of a JobPost is a foreign_key reference to another table (`company_id`). I'd like to add a `belongs_to :company` reference in the JobPost model. It seems like this should be possible by doing something like

```
class JobPost < Post
  belongs_to :company do
    Company.find_by_id self.metadata['company_id']
  end
end
```

but that doesn't appear to work. Help?

Note: I am not necessarily intent on using `belongs_to` rather than writing needed methods like `def company` by hand, but I do need a way to eager load companies when listing job posts. If there's a way to do that eager loading without a `belongs_to` relation I'm all ears.

**Update1**

I have also tried the following, which doesn't appear to work either:

```
class JobPost < Post
  belongs_to :company, foreign_key: "(posts.metadata->>'company_id')::integer".to_sym
end
```

**Update2**

To be more clear about my intentions and need:

1) A JobPost `belongs_to` a Company, but a Post (and other subclasses of Post) does not. I'd prefer not to jankily add the `company_id` column to the `posts` table when it won't be used by the other subclasses.

2) A JobPost could justify having it's own table (perhaps the relationship with a Company is enough to justify it). There are reasons why this wouldn't be ideal, but if that's the only answer I'm open to it. I'd, however, like a more definitive "what you're trying to do can't be done" response before going down this road, though.

The primary question is whether you can customize `belongs_to` so that it uses the metadata column rather than expecting the foreign key to be a column in the table.

The secondary question is whether you can eager load companies alongside job posts without having that `belongs_to` relation set up.

Comment: I don't understand your ask as you are complicating it more than it is. Do you want A Post STI model with a JobPost subclass, does this Post class belongs_to a Company class

Comment: A Post does not belong to a Company, but a JobPost does. The `posts` table does not have a column for `company_id` and therefore cannot use `belongs_to :company`. The `posts` table DOES have a `metadata` column. A JobPost uses that `metadata` column to store a `company_id`. However, if you add `belongs_to :company` to the JobPost class, you'll get an undefined column error. The question is whether it is possible to write your own implementation of `belongs_to` so that it looks into the metadata column rather than relying on a `company_id` column in the table. Or, can you sidestep the issue.

Comment: can you index 20% record of a column with a name and other 80% record of the same column with another column name? unfortunately rails is not that smart yet. hope it answers! you can inherit child classes in STI still they belong to one single Table

Comment: it sounds like you might not be familiar with the pattern of using a metadata column with STI to include data specific to each subclass on only those records. so in a way, yes you can have only a certain percentage of your `posts` table include the `company_id` data point when it lives in the metadata column. perhaps someone more familiar with that pattern may come across this and offer a solution, but thanks again for your responses and my apologies for not being crystal clear with the initial question.

Comment: again you are getting confused with rails relational mapping and with with storing records in a table, sounds like arguing of apples and oranges, you can certainly tag 20% data as A type and store corresponding values/jsonb metadata whatever of A type, similarly B type and etc, however when you have to map a table with rails association you map one entire column of the table as foreign key (not 20% records) to another tables primary key. suggest to read some basic concepts on rails associations before going into STI to include metadata or anything as such. thank you for your understanding.

Comment: rails provides the ability to add a scope to `belongs_to` in order to "retrieve a specific record or customize the generated query when you access the associated object" (via the docs). it seems like it would be possible to use this functionality to instruct rails to use the metadata column instead of a column named for the foreign_key. i am trying to get an answer as to whether this is possible, and i have provided a couple examples of my attempts to figure out that syntax in my question. i know how simple associations work, i want to know if what i'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: I understand your desperate attempts to get under the hood with your wanting. atm all is this what I can. ll update in case magically come across anything close, keeping it open further if you manage instructing rails as per your ask, or in fact anyone else with regards above would be an interesting finding for me

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

**UPD 2**

You need to add "company_id" column to the base class of your STI table. If JobPost inherits from Post, and it should have "company_id" then add the "company_id" column to Post (base table).

Remember STI stands for "Single Table Inheritance" so there is only one table on database schema level. Imagine a column of a Post table, where few data records are the foreign key entries for Companies with company_id and what about the other records of this column with non JobPost subclass types, are they null/empty? Hence the relationship is defined with parent STI table and subclass inherits these relations. Additional type column in STI defines the subclass type.

Check [here](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails)

You may need to dig further on [Polymorphic classes](http://www.archonsystems.com/devblog/2011/12/20/rails-single-table-inheritance-with-polymorphic-association/) instead of STI if both JobPost and Post have relationship with Company, else create two separate model, as they tend do have some unique relationships and column fields.

**UPD**

*Based on updated ask*

1. app/model/company.rb

```html
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :posts 
    delegate :jobposts, to: :posts
end
```

2. app/model/post.rb

```html
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :company 
    self.inheritance_column = :ptype 

    scope :job_posts, -> { where(ptype: 'JobPost') } 

    def self.ptype
      %w(JobPost)
    end

end
```

3. app/models/jobpost.rb

```html
class JobPost < Post; end
```

4. Create a company

```html
company = Company.create!(company_params)
```

5. Create some posts and add them to the company

```html
company.posts << JobPost.new(jobpost_params)
```

6. To fetch jobpost by company relationship

```html
company.job_posts
```

In case you are storing company_id in jsonb in any which column, just format your jobpost_params hash input accordingly and it should do the deed for you

**OLD ASK**

To find by primary key

```
Company.find(id)
```

In your case, id is self.metadata['company_id']

To find by other keys

```
Company.find_by(key: value)
```

Company.find_by_id is no more recommended

Please remove do and end after belongs_to in your model, instead in your controller you can write:

```
Jobpost.all.each do |x|
    # your do
end
```

regarding foreign key, as rails is convention over configuration, it by default includes company_id reference to Jobpost which you can change in your Company.rb model

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! What I'm really looking for is a way to set up a `belongs_to` company relation on the JobPost model so that I can eager load companies associated with each job post. The Rails documentation indicates that you can write a custom implementation of `belongs_to` with a scope or block, which is what I'm trying to do here. If I just load all JobPost records in the controller and then try to access the company object in the view from there, it will lead to N+1 queries, which I'm trying to avoid.

Also, `find_by_id` returns nil for no results; `find` returns an error.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a bit more clear about where I'm expecting that `belongs_to` to live. Also, your answer appears to indicate that the `companies` table should hold the foreign key, but `belongs_to` expects the foreign key in the `posts` table.

Comment: just add belongs_to :company. use includes to avoid [N+1] query

Comment: `belongs_to :company` only works if the `company_id` is stored as a column on the `posts` table. in my example it's stored in a jsonb metadata column. the question is how to use scopes/blocks to rewrite the `belongs_to` implementation so that it looks inside the metadata instead of expecting the `company_id` column, or alternatively, how to sidestep the `belongs_to` issue entirely.

Comment: one way to create job post is from hash params, Jobpost.create(company_id: params[:company_id], other_keys: values), this you can write as a scope or before_create, with belongs_to relation you have the association with JobPost by company_id and you can use jobpost as chain methods on company instances

Comment: I appreciate your efforts here BigB but I still don't think you're addressing the question. I don't have any issue creating job posts, or finding a company once I have a JobPost record loaded. The issue is entirely trying to fix N+1 queries for the specific metadata situation I have. If I can get `belongs_to` to work with the metadata column, then I can easily include the relation in my query. If there's a way to eager load without the `belongs_to` relation, that would work too. Perhaps there are other angles that I'm not even considering.

Comment: your ask on STI to have a separate child class column self answers from STI conceptual point. I would address you to use Polymorphic classes instead of STI

Comment: I appreciate your effort here BigB, and I don't want to waste more of your time. I know how to set up a basic `belongs_to` relation, and while your proposed solution will work technically, it's not ideal because not every subclass of Post should belong to a Company. Polymorphic relations are not the answer here either (a JobPost `belongs_to` a Company only, not multiple models). I could break a JobPost into its own table, but there are some reasons why that wouldn't be ideal either. I remain curious if anyone knows how to modify `belongs_to` so that it uses the metadata column.

Comment: Dude, do not mix mix up two things. 1. you can fetch metadata column from a table and clone it in company_id, it's possible by writing a #before_create #before_validate step or passing metadata and restructure hash param. 2. do not complicate building a relation (belongs_to) only on a inherited class with condition same relation does not exist on parent as it defies single table fundamental concept. I will appreciate if you put your questions next time straightforward with more clarity as it saves time in answering